# JavaScript error: push is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, runtime-error

I am trying to add and remove elements from "events". 
I don't know how to do it. Can anyone help me, please. I have tried with splice() too.

```
  var events =
  [
    { name: "Meeting 1", date: "Aug 2 2017", hour: "18:15" },
    { name: "Meeting 2", date: "Aug 1 2017", hour: "09:21" },
    { name: "Team", date: "Aug 1 2017", hour: "18:30" },

    { name: "St Mary Day", date: "Aug 15 2017", hour: "00:00" },
    { name: "St Andrew Day", date: "Nov 30 2017", hour: "00:00" },
    { name: "ROU National Day", date: "Dec 01 2017", hour: "00:00" },
    { name: "1st Day of Christmas", date: "Dec 25 2017", hour: "00:00" },
    { name: "2nd Day of Christmas", date: "Dec 26 2017", hour: "00:00" },
    { name: "Company Holiday", date: "Dec 27 2017", hour: "00:00" },
    { name: "Company Holiday", date: "Dec 28 2017", hour: "00:00" },
    { name: "Company Holiday", date: "Dec 29 2017", hour: "00:00" }
  ];



function myFunction() {
  console.log("myfunction");
  var input = document.getElementById('mod').value;
  console.log("input is" + input);

  events.forEach(function (events) {
    console.log("enum events");
    console.log(events.name);

    if (events.name == input) {
      var length = events.length;
      console.log("aici");
      events.push({ "name": "Tony Montana", "date": "Aug 3 2017", "hour": "18:00" });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Provide a better explanation of the behavior you are looking for. Broken code is not a good substitute for a proper explanation. Take some time to read [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var events =
  [
    { name: "Meeting 1", date: "Aug 2 2017", hour: "18:15" },
    { name: "Meeting 2", date: "Aug 1 2017", hour: "09:21" },
    { name: "Team", date: "Aug 1 2017", hour: "18:30" },
    { name: "St Mary Day", date: "Aug 15 2017", hour: "00:00" },
    { name: "St Andrew Day", date: "Nov 30 2017", hour: "00:00" },
    { name: "ROU National Day", date: "Dec 01 2017", hour: "00:00" },
    { name: "1st Day of Christmas", date: "Dec 25 2017", hour: "00:00" },
    { name: "2nd Day of Christmas", date: "Dec 26 2017", hour: "00:00" },
    { name: "Company Holiday", date: "Dec 27 2017", hour: "00:00" },
    { name: "Company Holiday", date: "Dec 28 2017", hour: "00:00" },
    { name: "Company Holiday", date: "Dec 29 2017", hour: "00:00" }
  ];



events.forEach(function (event) {
    if (event.name == "Meeting 2") {
    
       // Removes the "Meeting 2" element
      events = events.filter(evt => evt.name != "Meeting 2")
      
      // Pushes the "Tony Montana" element
      events.push({ "name": "Tony Montana", "date": "Aug 3 2017", "hour": "18:00" });
    }
});
console.log("events array is now", events)
```

Regarding the elements you want to remove, your code shows no attempt at removing elements, so I don't know the condition to remove stuff. But you can always filter your array, for instance :

```
events = events.filter( event => event.name!=="Meeting 2" )
```

will remove the element with `name : "Meeting 2"`.

Comment: The error from push() disappear but it doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: admin.html:159 Uncaught TypeError: events.filter is not a function
    at admin.html:159
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at myFunction (admin.html:153)  I get this error. "doesn't work" I mean it doesn't remove the element.

Comment: This error happens inside the `forEach`. This means that you're still re-using the same `events` variable, instead of a scoped variable like `event` (singular). This means that you're overwriting your original `events` array with the first object it contains, transforming it into an object and losing the original data. Objects have no `.filter` method, which is why you get this error. REPLACE `forEach(function (events)` with `forEach(function (event)` and try with `event.filter` and it will work.

Comment: I have made a full working snippet, with element removal and push, you can't say "it doesn't work" ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot! :D I am new to JS